# Automatically insert addin in Excel Online when opening addin-embedded document in WOPI client

Tags: excel, office-js, ms-wopi

We've been developing a JS addin for Excel Online/Desktop Excel and one of the major issues that we are still having is that we can't seem to get the addin to automatically insert when we open it in Office Online (users have to go through the process of inserting it through the Ribbon). Our application uses the MS-WOPI integration and acts as the host page for Office Online.

We noticed that embedding this Script Lab addin into an excel document - https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-OOXML-EmbedAddin - is actually giving us the behaviour that we want - IF we upload the document into OneDrive and open it from there. It seems that opening the file in Office Online through OneDrive will automatically insert and load the Script Lab addin.

However, when we try uploading the same Script Lab embedded document in our application (i.e. serving it through WOPI) we don't see the same automatic insertion/loading of the addin when we try to open the file in Office Online in the host iframe.

**Is it possible to get a JS addin to automatically insert into a WOPI served document when you open it in Office Online? Or is this a functionality specific to OneDrive?**

Answer (score 1):

Auto open in browser/online platform is only supported for One drive/O365-admin-hosted add-ins only. Wopi or on-perm platforms don’t support this feature.

Comment: Are there any plans to add this functionality for WOPI/On-prem?

Comment: There is no such plan at the moment. Thanks.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Is this feature added to Office Online Server?